The return json file of a post request in FastAPI is not showing in React
I have this Fastapi post request which receives 2 files, process them to return a json file with a list of people to unfollow. In the fastapi swagger the return show the list of unfollowers, I also have the frontend in react connected to the backend Fastapi, and is working cause the write function gives me the return df_result1 in my local computer. I would like to know if there is a way to show the list df_result1 in the React frontend?
When i try console.log(response.data) is show undefined
python code
@read_file.post("/upload_followers")
async def create_upload_followers(followers_file: UploadFile, following_file: UploadFile):
    """
    Process followers and following obtained in the format that instagram gives, and return a list of the ones that don't follow you back.

    Args:
        followers_file (UploadFile): Uploaded followers data file.
        following_file (UploadFile): Uploaded following data file.

    Returns:
        Pandas.DataFrame: DataFrame containing usernames that don't follow you back.
    """
    try:
        if not (followers_file.content_type == 'application/json' and following_file.content_type == 'application/json'):
            raise ValueError('Invalid file format. Please upload JSON files.')
        #Read file
        followers_read = await followers_file.read()
        following_read = await following_file.read()
        #upload file
        followers_data = json.loads(followers_read)
        following_data = json.loads(following_read)
        #list comprehension for getting the specific values of the file provided by instagram
        valores_followers = [inner_item['value'] for item in followers_data for inner_item in item.get("string_list_data", [])]
        valores_following = [inner_item['value'] for item in following_data['relationships_following'] for inner_item in item.get("string_list_data", [])]
        #to dataframe 
        df_followers = pd.DataFrame(valores_followers, columns=['username'])
        df_following = pd.DataFrame(valores_following, columns=['username'])
        #merge to only leave the following that also dont follow me, and mark them to identify them easily
        result1 = pd.merge(df_following, df_followers, on='username', how='left', indicator=True)
        result1['_merge'] = result1['_merge'].map({'left_only':'unfollow', 'both':'keep'})
        #global df_result
        df_result = result1[result1['_merge'] == 'unfollow']
        df_result1 = df_result.to_json()
        
        with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(df_result1)

        return df_result1
    
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions
        return JSONResponse(content={'error': str(e)}, status_code=400)

React code
import { useState } from "react";

function FileForm() {
    const [fileFollowers, setFileFollowers] = useState(null);
    const [fileFollowing, setFileFollowing] = useState(null)
    const handleFileInputChangeFollowers = (event) => {
        //console.log(event.target)
        setFileFollowers(event.target.files[0])
    }
    const handleFileInputChangeFollowing = (event) => {
        setFileFollowing(event.target.files[0])
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        //prevent default action of sending data to server
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        //name of the file FastApi receives
        formData.append('followers_file', fileFollowers);
        formData.append('following_file', fileFollowing)

        try {
            const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/upload_followers"
            const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("File uploaded sucessfully!");
                console.log(response.data);
                // const processedData = response.data.result2
                // alert(`Result: ${processedData}`);
            } else {
                console.error("Failed to uplead file.");
            }

        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Upload file</h1>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div style={{marginBottom: "20px"}}>
                    <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInputChangeFollowers}/>
                    <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInputChangeFollowing}/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>

            {fileFollowers && <p>{fileFollowers.name}</p>}
            {fileFollowing && <p>{fileFollowing.name}</p>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default FileForm;

Is not an error with origins all working good
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*']
)


Did you verify what the API returns in your browser's network tools? Did you try looking at the complete response object to see what the contents are?

Please have a look at this answer and this answer , as well as this answer and this answer
